# How can I get value in database to jlist with hibernate?

Tags: java, database, swing, hibernate, jlist

I get classsroom name in here but I couldnTt take classroomId with Jlist.
How can i get classroomId? I want to show classroom namein jlist but at the same time , i want to take its classroomId.Plase help for this problem.

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query query2 = session.createQuery("FROM Senior.entity.Classroom CL ");
    List<Classroom> results2 = query2.list();
    ////////List_2 için if /////////////////////
    if (results2.size() > 0) {
        Iterator iterate = results2.iterator();
        final Classroom resultAccoun2t = (Classroom) iterate.next();
        list_2.removeAll();
        for (Classroom inv : results2) {

            my problem is here, i didnt take classrroomId like this;

            //list2.add(new ListItem(inv.getClassromId(),inv.getClassroomName()));
            defaultListModel2.addElement(inv.getClassroomName());
        }
    }
    ////////My class//


    class ListItem{
private int classroom_id;
private String classroomname;

public ListItem(int classroom_id, String classroom_name) {
    this.classroom_id = classroom_id;
    this.classroomname = classroom_name;
}

public int getClassroom_id() {
    return classroom_id;
}

public void setClassroom_id(int classroom_id) {
    this.classroom_id = classroom_id;
}

public String getClassroomname() {
    return classroomname;
}

public void setClassroomname(String classroom_name) {
    this.classroomname = classroomname;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return  classroomname ;
}
```

}

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and we'll try and figure out why it's not working... _Deal?_

Comment: How about you edit your question, instead of trying to put the code into an unreadable comment, an explain what's what not working and where you're having problems

Comment: I didn't take classroom id what i choose classroom name in jlsit

Comment: Edit your post, and put your code _there_. Then delete the useless comments. If I were to show you code in this comment formatting, do you think _you_ could debug/let alone read it?

Answer (score 1):

No need for the redundant `ListItem`. Just override the `toString()` in your `ClassRoom` and just add the `ClassRoom` object to the list.

```
class ClassRoom {

    private String name;
    private int id;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Id: " + id + " , Name: " + name;
    }
}
...
for (ClassRoom cls : classes) {
    model.addElement(cls);
}
```

---

Example

[image]

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestClassroomList {

    public TestClassroomList() {
        List<ClassRoom> classes = createList();
        DefaultListModel model = createModel(classes);
        JList list = new JList(model);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(list));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private List<ClassRoom> createList() {
        List<ClassRoom> classes = new ArrayList<>();
        classes.add(new ClassRoom(1, "Biology"));
        classes.add(new ClassRoom(2, "History"));
        classes.add(new ClassRoom(3, "Calculus"));
        classes.add(new ClassRoom(4, "Programming"));
        classes.add(new ClassRoom(5, "Data Structures"));
        classes.add(new ClassRoom(6, "Sociology"));
        return classes;
    }

    private DefaultListModel createModel(List<ClassRoom> classes) {
        DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
        for (ClassRoom cls : classes) {
            model.addElement(cls);
        }
        return model;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestClassroomList();
            }
        });
    }

    class ClassRoom {

        private String name;
        private int id;

        public ClassRoom(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Id: " + id + " , Name: " + name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer.I am using hibernate.How can i convert this.I mean i want to get value and id to jlist from database.

Comment: Your query return a `List<ClassRoom>`. Just override the `toString()` of the `ClassRoom` to the output you want. Then just add all your `ClassRoom` objects to the list.